# picture embedded in div overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a picture going out of its container.

```
<div id="home"  class="cadre">      

<div id="photo">
    <img style="height:80%;float:right;max-height:250px;" src="images/photo.jpg"/>
</div>

<div style="width:70%;">  

Some text
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant content of the CSS stylesheet:

```
img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

#photo{
    float: right;
    max-width:45%;
    height:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

.cadre {
color: black;
border-width: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 40px auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 95%;
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,.2);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset;
}
```

I am new to CSS so I probably made design mistakes, but still I don't understand how it is possible that the pictures goes out of the frame.

It also seems to depend on the OS/explorer, as it works fine on Windows/Chrome but not on Linux/Firefox.

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` to `#photo`

Comment: won't it just hide the overflow instead of reducing the photo to the appropriate size ?

Comment: unrelated to the question: you could avoid odd rules like `width: 45%` and `width: 95%` if you use `box-sizing: border-box`. now you can use `50%` and `100%` as you intend.

Comment: I put the background of the div photo in red, and this div goes far below the actual picture, I don't see how to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to solve your parent-to-child width problem:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"> 
        <div id="pic">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6xO92YTljrxvGfxHRnZ_F-jjYGQvfRST-18K3cJhJYPNfBlLTdg"/>
        </div>
        <div id="text">
            some text
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            other text
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    max-height: auto;
    background: red;
    display: table;
}
.inner {
    display: table-row;
}
#pic {
    float: right;
    height: 180px;
    max-height: 100%
}
#text {
    width:70%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I don't want to give a size for the img, I want it to match the size of the text.

Comment: It seems to work now, I didn't understand everything but thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to define parent `div` where the photo is embedded in a way that does not allow for any element to go `overboard`

```css
#photo {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Should do the trick in your situation.

Comment: it does not seem to change anything :/

Comment: and if I add this in #home instead of #photo the div becomes huge !

Comment: the problem here seems to be that "photo" overflows "home"

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, maybe do a fiddle for us to get the picture.

If your picture is going over your div "overflow:hidden" should have resolved that.

It becomes huge cuz you set it to be relative to #home div which is bigger in size. Please be more specific so we can help.

Comment: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8fqdt0s/1/
What I want is the image to stay in the red div, and to adjust automatically to the size of the block of text.